# Blank Result When Filtering ForeignKey values in Django ModelchoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have three models and they serve as 'Foreignkey' to each other.

Hotel models

```
class Hotel(model.Models):
  user= models.ForeignKey(User)
  name= models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='hotel_name')
  address= models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='hotel_address') 
  #more fields
```

Rooms models

```
class HotelRooms(models.Model):
    hotel= models.ForeignKey(Hotel, related_name='myhotels')
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    room_name=models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Room Name')
    #other fields
```

HotelCalendar models

```
class HotelCalendar(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    hotel=models.ForeignKey(Hotel)
    hotelrooms=models.ForeignKey(HotelRooms)
     #other fields
```

Now, I want to display all rooms that belongs to a hotel in HotelCalender form in order for the owner to select the room he/she wants to update and save.

HotelCalendar form

```
class HotelCalendarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(HotelCalendarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['hotelrooms'].queryset=  HotelRooms.objects.filter(hotel=self.instance.hotel_id)
```

Template

```
<form id="post_form" method="post" action=""
      enctype="multipart/form-data">

     {% csrf_token %}

     {{  HotelCalendarForm.as_p }}


    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Views

```
def hotel_calendar_view(request, hotel_id):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=HotelCalendarForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data=form.cleaned_data
            newbookdate=HotelCalendar(
                user=request.user,
                hotel=Hotel.objects.get(id=hotel_id),
                hotelrooms=data['hotelrooms'],)
            newbookdate.save()
            return render(request, 'notice.html')
            #other code here
```

When I load the form, it won't return any value, The modelchoicefield is just blank.

What am I missing?

Comment: Check that HotelRooms.objects.filter(hotel=self.instance.hotel_id)
returns anything...

Comment: it doesn't return anything.

Comment: That's because self.instance is `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to populate the `hotelrooms` field with the filtered results by the hotel when the form is loaded on a GET request. If that's the case the field wont load any data as the `instance` variable will be `None`.

For the initial data you need to pass the hotel id to the form when it is being initialized on the GET request and in the form, load the data using the hotel id and not `instance.hotel_id`. For example:

#### views.py

```
@login_required
def hotel_calendar_view(request, hotel_id):
    if request.method=="POST":
        ## code to post the form data
    else:
        context = {
            'HotelCalendarForm’: HotelCalendarForm(hotel_id=hotel_id),
            'hotel': Hotel.objects.get(id=hotel_id)
        }
        return render(request, 'hotels/hotel_calendar.html', context)
    # return default response
```

and then in your forms:

#### forms.py

```
class HotelCalendarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        hotel_id = kwargs.pop(“hotel_id”, None)
        super(HotelCalendarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if hotel_id:
            self.fields['hotelrooms'].queryset=HotelRooms.objects.filter(hotel=hotel_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the line

```
self.fields['hotelrooms'].queryset = HotelRooms.objects.filter(hotel=self.instance.hotel_id)
```

to

```
self.fields['hotelrooms'].queryset = HotelRooms.objects.filter(hotel=self.instance.hotel)
```

When you are filtering on foreign key it expects a model instance. If you would want to filter on foreign key you would have to do it like this:

```
HotelRooms.objects.filter(hotel_id=self.instance.hotel_id)
```

If you want to know more read https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did this, self.fields['hotelrooms'].queryset= HotelRooms.objects.filter(hotel=self.instance.hotel) and it didn't show any form in the template. My template is the same as what I wrote in my question.  I also tried this, HotelRooms.objects.filter(hotel_id=self.instance.hotel_id) the field returns blank field.. no values were returned.

Comment: Well maybe you just don't have any hotel rooms for that hotel?